# Poisoner's Nook Plants don't seem to grow back

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I've successfully completed the Dark Brotherhood Questline in Skyrim and purchased the Poisoner's Nook Alchemy Table + Garden for the Sanctuary. However, it appears that the plants haven't yet grown back, which is a pity.

Is there any confirmed timespan in which the plants should grow back?

Comment: If it's like Oblivion it should respawn within 3 in-game days.

Comment: That's exactly the point, it's been about 15 ingame days and they haven't grown back.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The cell reset time in Skyrim is a whopping 30 days according to what inspection of the ESM is so far possible with existing Fallout 3 tools. So rest assured, the nook's plants will regrow eventually, it'll just take a long while.

For those who think this is way too long for streets to be cleared of bodies and plants to regrow, there is already a mod to set the reset time to 1, 2, 3, or 7 days: [Skyrim Respawn](http://skyrimnexus.com/downloads/file.php?id=89).

Answer (score 2):

It is only 10 days, but entering the sanctuary before the time is up, will reset the time forcing another 10 day wait.